# Fetch a remote branch into an existing repo that contains only one branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I have been cloning a single branch only

`git clone -b v1.1.1 --single-branch [myrepo].git`

I've made changes that should actually be on branch v1.1.2, which exists on github.

I'm trying to fetch v1.1.2 to my existing repo, then move all my uncommitted files from v1.1.1 to v1.1.2

I've tried:

`git clone -b v1.1.2 --single-branch [myrepo].git`

But get

`fatal: destination path [myrepo] already exists and is not an empty directory`

Also from within the directory

`git fetch v1.1.2`

But get

`fatal: v1.1.2 does not appear to be a git repository`
`fatal: could not read from remote repository`

Can anyone help fetching another branch to the existing repo? and then moving my changes to the new branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't really "fetch a branch" (whatever that would mean: the term *branch* is ambiguous, in Git).<sup>1</sup>  You really fetch *commits*.  However, at the end of the commit-fetching process, `git fetch` *can* update various *names* in your local repository as well.  Normally these are *remote-tracking names* (which Git formally calls *remote-tracking branch names*, but that poor word *branch*, already nearly bludgeoned to death, is doing nothing useful in that phrase).

> I have been cloning a single branch only [via]
> `git clone -b v1.1.1 --single-branch [myrepo].git`

This creates what Git calls a "single-branch clone".  What that is, is a clone in which `git fetch` operations default to:

- fetching commits *reachable from* a single particular branch name in the remote repository; and
- updating only that one remote-tracking name in the local repository.

Git achieves this by setting `remote.origin.fetch` (assuming the remote is named `origin`) to `+refs/heads/v1.1.1:refs/remotes/origin/v1.1.1`.

> I'm trying to fetch v1.1.2 to my existing repo

What you want, in other words, is what we might call a "two-branch clone" if we follow the model Git provides (not a very good model, but...).  This requires altering the default fetch setting.  Fortunately, you don't have to fiddle directly with the `remote.origin.fetch` line(s) to do this.  The `git remote` command can do this for you:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin v1.1.2
```

will do the job, adding a correct second `remote.origin.fetch` line.

(Side note: `v` names, in many repositories, are reserved for *tag* names rather than *branch* names.  But that's just a convention, and apparently one your repository rejects.)  After that, just run `git fetch origin` and `origin/v1.1.2` will appear, assuming of course that there's a `v1.1.2` branch in the Git repository over in `origin`.

> then move all my uncommitted files from v1.1.1 to v1.1.2

That *may* be possible: you can try running `git switch v1.1.2` (using the `--guess` mode to create a `v.1.1.2` based on `origin/v1.1.2`).  But it may not be possible.  (For the gory details on when it's possible, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).  If you can't just switch, either make a commit, or perhaps use `git stash`.  I personally don't like `git stash`: I'd make a new branch first with `git switch -c` or `git checkout -b`, then commit, then switch to `v1.1.2`, then cherry-pick the commit made on the temporary branch.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Since the term *branch* is so poorly defined, we could just say that whatever commits we fetched were "the branch", and then we fetched "a branch".  But that's kind of the Humpty Dumpty way of defining [glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll%27s_Through_the_Looking-Glass).  I find the whole thing unsatisfying: too close to the philosophical fallacy of [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).  That is, we start by saying "git fetch fetches a branch", then define "branch" as whatever git fetch fetches, and we end up no wiser than when we started.

Comment: `--single-branch` creates `remote.origin.fetch` limited to a specific branch. It makes sense but not friendly enough.

Answer (score 0):

From within the existing repository, you can fetch the desired branch `v1.1.2` from `[myrepo].git` into a new local branch with the same name (`v1.1.2`):

```
git fetch origin v1.1.2:v1.1.2
```

or if the repo isn't known as `origin`, then

```
git fetch [myrepo].git v1.1.2:v1.1.2
```

Left of `:` is the branch/commit to be fetched
Right of `:` is the new local branch name

If you omit the `:v1.1.2` part, then the fetched commit will be temporarily available as `FETCH_HEAD`.
You could use that to e.g. run `git branch v1.1.2 FETCH_HEAD` or `git checkout -b v1.1.2 FETCH_HEAD` manually.

Note:
You probably want to adjust your `.git/config` after, if you want the single-branch repository to automatically fetch `v1.1.2` in future.